# In an ASP.NET MVC 3 view, how to handle all form submission in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

In this ASP.NET MVC 3 view, I need to control form submission completely via JavaScript (I use jQuery). Specifically, my form submission logic contacts the server via [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), which is a Comet framework (an improvement on Ajax, basically).

How can I install a JavaScript handler for any type of submission of forms in the view (e.g., via clicking the submit button or pressing Enter in a field)? The handler also needs to completely disable form submission while the server is processing.

Keep in mind that I'm doing unobtrusive client-side validation of forms in the view as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Or do it manually by adding a global script to all pages:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            // client validation passed => send it with AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize()
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you recommend jQuery Form wrt. integration with ASP.NET MVC, unobtrusive client-side validation, custom submission etc.?

Comment: @aknuds1, yes I would strongly recommend it. Personally I use it all the time.

Comment: That plugin was surprisingly easy to apply. Thanks for the tip!